# using class ? c++ & sfml and 15 characters in the title

Tags: c++, sfml

When using class ?

This question is probably evident for you but i know and learned how to create class and how it's working but i don't know when using it.

I think i can cut my program with class but i don't know when i must do it.

I would like to share my code but i can't paste it completely in the topic post.

Include

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
```

Constantes

```
//Constantes ecran
    int tailleEcranX = 1280;
    int tailleEcranY = 720;

//Constantes perso
        int scalePerso = 3;
        int tailleSpriteX = 32;
        int tailleSpriteY = 48;
        int speed(4);
        int speedSprinte(20);
        int milieuSpriteX = (tailleSpriteX/2)*scalePerso;
        int milieuSpriteY = (tailleSpriteY/2)*scalePerso;

        int pv = 100;
        unsigned int pvMax = 100;
```

Initialisation

```
//Initiation des dessins
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    sf::RectangleShape rect;
    sf::Texture perso;
    sf::Sprite sprite_perso;
    sf::View view;
    sf::RectangleShape rectCol;

    sf::RectangleShape pvBar;
    sf::RectangleShape pvMaxBar;

    enum Dir{Down,Left,Right,Up};

sf::Vector2i anim (1,Down);

#include "gestion_clavier.h"
```

Main

```
    int main()
    {
    //{ Positionnement des objets

        window.create(sf::VideoMode(tailleEcranX , tailleEcranY), "The Game I");
        window.setPosition(sf::Vector2i(500,250));
        window.setFramerateLimit(60);

        rect.setFillColor(sf::Color(255,0,0));
        rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(tailleEcranX-10,tailleEcranY-10));
        rect.setPosition(5,5);
        rect.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(255,255,255));
        rect.setOutlineThickness(3);

        rectCol.setFillColor(sf::Color(0,0,200));
        rectCol.setSize(sf::Vector2f(50,50));
        rectCol.setPosition(400,500);
        rectCol.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(255,255,255));
        rectCol.setOutlineThickness(1);

        sf::Clock time;

    //}

    //{Chargement des Sprites

    if (!perso.loadFromFile("link/srpite.png",sf::IntRect(0,0,96,192)))
    {
        std::cout<<"erreur chargement player image"<<std::endl;
    }
    sprite_perso.setTexture(perso);
    sprite_perso.setPosition(tailleEcranX/2-milieuSpriteX,tailleEcranY/2-milieuSpriteY);

    //}

    //{ Game Loop

        while (window.isOpen())
        {
            sf::Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                    window.close();
            }


    ProcessInput();
    //gestion_clavier();


    if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Z)||sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S)||sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)||sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Q))
    {
        if (time.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds()>= 50)
        {
                    anim.x++;
            if(anim.x*tailleSpriteX >= perso.getSize().x)
               anim.x=0;

                time.restart();
        }
    }


    sprite_perso.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(anim.x*tailleSpriteX,anim.y*tailleSpriteY,tailleSpriteX,tailleSpriteY));
    sprite_perso.setScale(scalePerso,scalePerso);

        pvBar.setFillColor(sf::Color(20,255,30));
        pvBar.setSize(sf::Vector2f(4*pv,10));
        pvBar.setPosition(20,20);

        pvMaxBar.setFillColor(sf::Color(0,0,0));
        pvMaxBar.setSize(sf::Vector2f(4*pvMax,10));
        pvMaxBar.setPosition(20,20);
        pvMaxBar.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(255,255,255));
        pvMaxBar.setOutlineThickness(2);

        if(pv>=pvMax)
        {
            pv=pvMax;
        }

        if(pv<=0)
        {
            pv=0;
        }

    if(
    (std::abs((sprite_perso.getPosition().x+milieuSpriteX)-(rectCol.getPosition().x+50/2))<50)
       &&
    (std::abs((sprite_perso.getPosition().y+milieuSpriteY)-(rectCol.getPosition().y+50/2))<50)
       )
    {
        std::cout<<"collision"<<std::endl;
        pv--;
        std::cout<<pv<<std::endl;
    }

    //Dessinage
            window.draw(rect);
            window.draw(rectCol);
            window.draw(sprite_perso);

            window.draw(pvMaxBar);
            window.draw(pvBar);


            window.display();
            window.clear();

    }

    //}


        return 0;
    }
    //}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I ask if it's good for the moment and if someone can explain to me when I have to use a class

Comment: "Dessinage"? C'est nouveau :p

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to understand a lot of your code, since the variables seem to be written in french, but I can give you some general advice.

When deciding when to use a class, you should first think about the contents of your program in terms of objects. For example: if there is a character/person, or something you would consider an independent object in the real world, there's a reasonable chance that should be its own class. The class should contain whatever is needed to describe the object, like it's position, scale, sprite, etc. Here's an example:

```
class Person
{
    private:
        sf::Vector2f position;
        sf::Sprite sprite;
    public:
        void setPosition(sf::Vector2f newPosition);
        sf::Vector2f getPosition();
        void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);
}
```

If you want your class to have position and such, I recommend deriving from the `sf::Transformable` class to save you some time and effort. You can also derive from `sf::Drawable` if you want to draw your object using `window.draw(person)` like many of the default SFML objects can.

```
class Person : public sf::Transformable, public sf::Drawable
{
    private:
        sf::Sprite sprite;
        void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
        {
            states.transform *= getTransform();
            target.draw(sprite, states);
        }
}
```

You have a number of variables you say are constants. If that is the case, then it's considered good practice to mark them as such using `const`. For example:

```
const int scalePerso = 3;
```

This stops you from changing the value in the future and causing bugs you need to track down.

I also noticed you are defining seperate variables for X and Y positions. This is unnecessary, since SFML defines the sf::Vector2 type. For example:

```
const sf::Vector2f tailleSpritePosition(32.f, 48.f);
```

instead of

```
int tailleSpriteX = 32;
int tailleSpriteY = 48;
```

You're also mixing types quite a bit by passing integers into functions that accept float values. This is also considered bad practice. If you want to change an integer into a float, you should explicitly cast it using `(float)` like so:

```
rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f((float)tailleEcranX - 10.f, (float)tailleEcranY - 10.f));
```

making sure to add the letter `f` to the end of your literals to tell the compiler those are floating point values too. Alternatively, you could just define your variables to be of type `float` to start off with in some cases.

**Feel free to ask if there is anything you don't understand.**